# Changing LineageOS build kernel version string

Tags: android, linux-kernel

Is there a way to easily change the hostname and username in the kernel version string? A flag? Some other config file I have to change? I did find this though that would solve my problem http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Kernel/Build/CustomiseVersionString, but the links were dead thus it's useless.

(I'm building LineageOS 11 for LG L9 II (D605) if that matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to temporarily rename your PC and create a new user.